# Property does not exist on type 'Ref<never[]>[]'

Tags: vue.js, typescript

В консоль получаю ошибки вида:

1. TS2339: Property 'shop' does not exist on type '(Ref<never[]> | ((id: number) => Promise))[]'.
2. TS2339: Property 'getShop' does not exist on type '(Ref<never[]> | ((id: number) => Promise))[]'.

Почему они возникают при импорте функции и как их исправить?
Пример кода:

```
// useShop.ts
import { ref } from "vue"

export default function useShop() {
  const shop = ref([])

  const getShop = async (id: number) => {
    // Получение каких-то данных
    // И присваивание
    shop.value = []
  }

  return [shop, getShop]
}

// Detail.vue
export default defineComponent({
  components: {},
  setup() {
    const { shop, getShop } = useShop()
    return {}
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

В useShop.ts необходимо возвращать объект, нежели массив.

```
return {shop, getShop}
```